# How can I implement a blocking process in a single slot without freezing the GUI?

Tags: user-interface, qt, events, signals-slots

Let's say I have an event and the corresponding function is called.  This function interacts with the outside world and so can sometimes have long delays.  If the function waits or hangs then my UI will freeze and this is not desirable.  On the other hand, having to break up my function into many parts and re-emitting signals is long and can break up the code alot which would make hard to debug and less readable and slows down the development process.  Is there a special feature in event driven programming which would enable me to just write the process in one function call and be able to let the mainThread do its job when  its waiting?  For example, the compiler could reckognize a keyword then implement a return then re-emit signals connected to new slots automatically?  Why do I think this would be a great idea ;)  Im working with Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two options are threading, or breaking your function up somehow.

With threading, it sounds like your ideal solution would be [`Qt::Concurrent`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/threads-qtconcurrent.html).  If all of your processing is already in one function, and the function is pretty self-contained (doesn't reference member variables of the class), this would be easy to do.  If not, things might get a little more complicated.

For breaking your function up, you can either do it as you suggested and break it into different functions, with the different parts being called one after another, or you can do it in a more figurative way, but scattering calls to allow other processing inside your function.  I believe calling `processEvents()` would do what you want, but I haven't come across its use in a long time.  Of course, you can run into other problems with that unless you understand that it might cause other parts of your class to run once more (in response to other events), so you have to treat it almost as multi-threaded in protecting variables that have an indeterminate state while you are computing.

Comment: processEvents() sounds promising  ill try it. thx.  Ill be sure to keep in mind the problem it could bring up.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there a special feature in event driven programming which would enable me to just write the process in one function call and be able to let the mainThread do its job when its waiting?"

That would be a non-blocking process.

But your original query was, "How can I implement a blocking process in a single slot without freezing the GUI?"

Perhaps what you're looking for a way to stop other processing when some - any - process decides it's time to block? There are typically ways to do this, yes, by calling a method on one of the parental objects, which, of course, will depend on the specific objects you are using (eg a frame).

Look to the parent objects and see what methods they have that you'd like to use. You may need to overlay one of them to get your exactly desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle a GUI event by beginning a long-running task, and don't want the GUI to wait for the task to finish, you need to do it concurrently, by creating either a thread or a new process to perform the task.

You *may* be able to avoid creating a thread or process if the task is I/O-bound and occasional callbacks to handle I/O would suffice.  I'm not familiar with Qt's main loop, but I know that GTK's supports adding event sources that can integrate into a `select()` or `poll()`-style loop, running handlers after either a timeout or when a file descriptor becomes ready.  If that's the sort of task you have, you could make your event handler add such an event source to the application's main loop.